# Python regularized gradient descent for logistic regression

Tags: python, numpy, logistic-regression, gradient-descent, regularized

I'm trying to implement Gradient Descent (GD) (not stochastic one) for logistic regression in Python 3x. And have some troubles.

Logistic regression is defined as follows (1):
[logistic regression formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbPwR.png)

Formulas for gradients are defined as follows (2):
[gradient descent for logistic regression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGSDY.png)

**Description of data:**

- X is (Nx2)-matrix of objects (consist of positive and negative float numbers)
- y is (Nx1)-vector of class labels (-1 or +1)

**Task:** 
Implement gradient descent 1) with L2-regularization; and 2) without regularization. Desired results: vectors of weights.
Parameters: regularization rate *C*=10 for regularized regression and C=0 for unregularized regression; gradient step *k*=0.1; max.number of iterations = 10000; tolerance = 1e-5. 
Note: GD is converged if distance between weighs vectors from current and previous steps is less than tolerance (1e-5).

**Here is my implementation:**
*k* - gradient step;
*C* - regularization rate.

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(z):
    result = 1./(1. + np.exp(-z))
    return result

def distance(vector1, vector2):
    vector1 = np.array(vector1, dtype='f')    
    vector2 = np.array(vector2, dtype='f')
    return np.linalg.norm(vector1-vector2)

def GD(X, y, C, k=0.1, tolerance=1e-5, max_iter=10000):

    X = np.matrix(X)
    y = np.matrix(y)
    l=len(X)
    w1, w2 = 0., 0.  # weights (look formula (2) in the beginning of question)
    difference = 1.
    iteration = 1

    while(difference > tolerance):

        hypothesis = y*(X*np.matrix([w1, w2]).T)

        w1_updated = w1 + (k/l)*np.sum(y*X[:,0]*(1.-(sigmoid(hypothesis)))) - k*C*w1
        w2_updated = w2 + (k/l)*np.sum(y*X[:,1]*(1.-(sigmoid(hypothesis)))) - k*C*w2

        difference = distance([w1, w2], [w1_updated, w2_updated])
        w1, w2 = w1_updated, w2_updated
        if(iteration >= max_iter):
            break;

        iteration = iteration + 1

    return [w1_updated, w2_updated]  #vector of weights
```

Respectively:

```
# call for UNregularized GD: C=0
w = GD(X, y, C=0., k=0.1)
```

and

```
# call for regularized GD: C=10
w_reg = GD(X, y, C=10., k=0.1)
```

Here are the resuls (weights-vectors):

```
# UNregularized GD
[0.035736331265589463, 0.032464572442830832]

# regularized GD
[5.0979561973044096e-06, 4.6312243707352652e-06]
```

However, it should be (right answers for self-control):

```
# UNregularized GD
[0.28801877, 0.09179177]

# regularized GD
[0.02855938, 0.02478083]
```

**!!!** Please, can you tell me whats going wrong here? I'm sitting with this problem for three days in a row and still have no idea.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the sigmoid functions should be

```
def sigmoid(Z):
   A=1/(1+np.exp(-Z))
   return A
```

Try to run it again with this formula. Then, what is L?

Comment: Yes, right, I fixed sigmoid, but, unfortunatelly, it makes no difference because I used 1./sigmoid before so the result formula did not change.

Comment: I also fixed the issue with L (which was just term for better undestanding of the code - in fact, it is part of formula (2)).

Comment: Keep in mind that the results that you provided as correct do not present a difference that is smaller than the tolerance 1e-5, whereas those that you obtained are closer to t>d